# Java: Dynamic HTML Code

Tags: java, dynamic

I just started in Java HTML, and I'd like help making my HTML page dynamic. I have given by HTML code below that prints to my webpage, but now I want to create a program that will intake my text file then dynamically print it to my html page. Any suggestions, examples, or tutorials? Many online are far too advanced for me. Thank you!

```
<h1>
Which Proteins Are Rich in Particular Amino Acids?

<table border cellspacing=0 cellpadding=5>
<caption align=bottom>
    Generated by Me</caption>

<tr>
    <th> Amino Acids</th>
    <th> Proteins Rich in that Amino Acid</th>
    <th> Number of Residues</th>
    <th> Amino Acid Abundance</th>
    </tr>

<tr align=center>
    <th>Alanine(A)</th>
    <td>ATXN3</td>
    <td>11/33</td>
    <td>.333</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</h1>
```

Comment: are you talking about javascript?

Comment: No, I think he wants to use Java as server side.

Comment: Well...this is traditionally what JSP, ASP, and PHP are for. Dynamically generating HTML based on business-logic. Since you said "many online are far too advanced for me", I'd recommend using PHP for the task. Even if you have no experience in PHP, it's still very simple to learn how to script webpages with it.